# Adding properties to an empty object

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, nativescript

I have this code

```
var MY_OBJ = {};
MY_OBJ.test = function(){}
```

and I'm using Vscode, I get property test not defined.
How do I let this be just a warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will fix your problem

```
var MY_OBJ:any = {};
MY_OBJ.test = function(){}
```

Comment: So, essentially your proposal is to go behind TypeScript's back.

Comment: yes,but I think dashman needs to add properties to object dynamically so I thought this is a best solution.

Answer (score 8):

Define your object to have a `test` property:

```
var MY_OBJ: {test?: Function} = {};

MY_OBJ.test = function() { };
```

Or, set the property this way:

```
MY_OBJ['test'] = function() { };
```

For further type-safety, define `MY_OBJ` to be an object:

```
var MY_OBJ: { [propName: string]: any } = {};
```

This will prevent errors such as `MY_OBJ = 14;`.

If you intend this object to always have function valued keys, then

```
var MY_OBJ: { [propName: string]: Function } = {};
```

will prevent errors such as `MY_OBJ['test'] = 14;`.

If you're going to use `any` in the way proposed in the accepted answer, what's the point of using TypeScript in the first place?