# how to dynamically add a property to an object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

How can I dynamically add a property to an object in typescript?  Here's a sample method:

```
processSearchResults(responseObject)
{
    var blogPostSearchResults = Object.assign(new GetBlogPostsResponse(), responseObject);
    this.blogPostSearchResults = blogPostSearchResults.CollectionResults;

var authorList = ['John Smith', 'Bill Jones'];

    //append author list to each result
    for (var blogPost in this.blogPostSearchResults)
    {
        blogPost.AuthorList = authorList ;
    }
}
```

In the example above, I'm taking an object with a particular definition, and then trying to create and assign a new property dynamically to provide an additional structure for html template view binding.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You add properties just like in JavaScript. TS is a _static_ analyzer built on top of JS, it doesn't make sense to dynamically change the type annotations.

Comment: Perhaps he wants to declare a optional property in his Object type definition. It can be done using the question mark:

{
optionalValue?: string;
}

Comment: Maybe you want an indexable type?

Comment: I think you need to provide a [complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example if you want concrete help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding properties to an empty object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39792221/adding-properties-to-an-empty-object)